# Crash in only samsung note 2, Android 4.4

Tags: android

This is the crash:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2413)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2471)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900 (ActivityThread.java:175)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1308)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:146)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5602)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative (Native Method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:515)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:1283)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1099)
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main (Native Method)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: 
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView (LayoutInflater.java:626)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag (LayoutInflater.java:702)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate (LayoutInflater.java:761)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate (LayoutInflater.java:498)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate (LayoutInflater.java:398)
  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate (LayoutInflater.java:354)
  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView (AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:292)
  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView (AppCompatActivity.java:140)
  at com.bitcoinaverage.bitcoinapp.activities.MainActivity.onCreate (MainActivity.java:115)
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:5451)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate (Instrumentation.java:1093)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2377)
```

Here is my MainActivity (line 115): setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

and here is my activity_main.xml:

```
     <include
         layout="@layout/app_bar_dashboard"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent" />

     <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
         android:id="@+id/nav_view"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:layout_gravity="start"
         android:background="@color/colorPrimaryLight"
         android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
         app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_dashboard"
         app:itemTextColor="@color/textColorGrey"
         app:menu="@menu/navigation_drawer" />

 </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Here is app_bar_dashboard.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:background="@color/blackTwo"
     xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     tools:context="com.bitcoinaverage.bitcoinapp.activities.MainActivity">

     <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

         <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
             android:id="@+id/toolbar"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
             android:background="@color/blackTwo"
             app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

     </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

     <FrameLayout
         android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

 </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I have used material design theme in my project. App is crashing instantly as it is open on samsung note 2 which has android 4.4 with 2gb ram.
Can anyone please explain Why it is crashed ?

Here is build.gradle[app]:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.bitcoinaverage.bitcoinapp"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 13
        versionName "1.1.9"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dataBinding.enabled = true
    android.defaultConfig.vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile files('libs/joda-time-2.9.9.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
    compile 'android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.0.0-alpha5'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.0'
    compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:11.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:11.0.1'
    annotationProcessor 'android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.0.0-alpha5'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

style.xml

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:listDivider">@color/textColorGrey</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    <style name="interval_style">
        <item name="android:layout_width">0dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_weight">1</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/warmGreyTwo</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/dashboard_graph_interval_text_size</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
        <item name="android:paddingTop">10dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingBottom">10dp</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

style.xml[v21]

```
    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    </style>


</resources>
```

Comment: Can you show your build.gradle?

Comment: What is at `MainActivity.java:115` line ?

Comment: setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

Comment: make sure you are ussing correct `style` for different api

Comment: Can u please check ?

Comment: I have updated both styles.xml adn styles.xml[v21]